# Proper 'pythonic' and 'setuptools' way to write unit tests that _require_ authentication

Tags: python, setuptools, python-unittest, pypi

I'm working on an update to a pypi distributed package that uses a remote API.  I want to write some tests for that API.

I am planning on simulating the connection for some of the unittests and generating errors for others but some of the tests really should go through to the actual API, which obviously requires a username and password.

Is it acceptable practice to collect these from the command line via either CLI or console input, failing which, I simply skip the test when doing setuptools unit testing?  I haven't gotten a clear answer on this after googling quite a bit.

Comment: Something like VCR might help: https://github.com/kevin1024/vcrpy

Answer (score 1):

Consider using environment variables with default values that either raise an exception or tell the test to fail.

```
import os
import unittest

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.username = os.environ.get('API_USERNAME', None)
        self.password = os.environ.get('API_PASSWORD', None)

    def test_real_api(self):
        if self.username is None or self.password is None:
            raise Exception('API credentials required for this test!')
```

Environment variables can be easily specified wherever you decide to run your tests, while command line arguments and interactive console input can require more effort for stuff like plug-and-play continuous integration systems.

Comment: I was thinking that CLI options could be specified using the setuptools utilities for that function.